# InDesign - Replace text field from file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, text, indesign-scripting

I'm trying to make a document where on each page there is some text (e.g. name) that is updated based on a text file that contains the list of the desired text for each page. (Imagine a document with business cards and a text file with the names for the employees)

How can I make this in InDesign? I was trying to use a master page and some text variable, but couldn't figure out how to link in the text file as data source. Is this the right approach? Any other way, or script to achieve this?

Alternatively, if the same can be achieved in Illustrator, that would work as well!

Comment: Hi and welcome to gdse! It's called *data merge*. I'm sure there are several questions on the site about that. Don't have time to look for them right now. Read about data merge in InDesign here: https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html